# Java 8 is this assertion about finalize method correct?

Tags: java, finalize

I been reading the book *OCA Java SE 8 Programmer I Exam Guide* by Kathy Sierra + Bert Bates.

There is something about the finalize method I don't get it quite well. It states on page 218:

> Calling `finalize()` can actually result in saving an object from deletion.

Later on page 222:

> You can make an object ineligible for GC from within `finalize()`.

English is not my native language, but what I understand in both scenarios is that the `finalize()` method can prevent the object from being garbage collected? Is this so? Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: If you were to save somewhere a reference to the object in `finalize`, I would think that would prevent it from being GC'd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really more of a theoretical thing: objects are eligible for garbage collection when they aren't referenced from other *live* objects anymore.

Thus: you could *try* to create such a reference within `finalize()`. Which would then theoretically prevent the object from being removed.

There is actually a "pattern name" for that: [object resurrection](https://dzone.com/articles/java-immortal-objects-and-object-resurrection). Now, if this is a pattern, or more of an **anti** pattern is open for debate.

(personally: I would never do that, and I have never been in a situation where it would have been necessary to use this pattern)

Comment: Apart from this being a way to invoke some logic when Garbage Collector fiers and tries to collect the object in question, this really does not differ from simply storing a "global" reference to said object, correct?

Comment: @Fureeish Bear in mind that `finalize()` is only invoked once (if it's invoked at all). After referencing again the object, and later de-referencing, the `finalize()` method is not invoked again and the object is subject to being directly discarded.

Comment: @Fureeish Well, when you add references in some "global store", you would do that  at some **prior** point in time. So theoretically, that object **never** gets eligible, thus its finalize() will never be called.

Comment: @manouti the `finalize()` method of that object is not invoked again, but it doesn’t have to resurrect the `this` instance but could resurrect another object only reachable by this object under finalization. It could be stored into another object with a `finalize()`, to resurrect it an arbitrary number of times. But in fact, the invocation of `finalize()` **is** already a resurrection. Put an infinite loop into it, and the object stays forever, without the need to store a global reference. Do this as often as you have finalizer threads and *all* objects with nontrivial `finalize()` stay alive.

Answer (score 2):

Finalize is a method called by JVM and not by the user, this method is executed just before an object is being garbage collected, you can override the finalize method to do cleanup operations before the object is disposed or as the book stated it is possible that you can prevent the object from being garbage collected.

You can refer below code as an example of saving an object from being garbage collected.

```
class Example { 

    static Example y; 

    void func() { 
        Example x = new Example(); 
    } 

    pubic void finalize() { 

        y = this; // Putting the reference id 
        // of the current object 
        // into the static variable y 

        System.out.println("The object won't be collected by the garbage collector"); 

    } 

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        func(); // function called 
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes like this topic shows. https://dzone.com/articles/java-immortal-objects-and-object-resurrection

Comment: @chiperortiz yes, when the method finalize is called you can always refer to the object being destroyed using this keyword and do whatever you require from that particular object, one such usage is resurrection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is true.

`finalize()` method is being called when GC decides that the object should be deleted but it doesn't mean, that the object will be removed anyway right after `finalize` finishes.

```
IT DOESN'T WORK THIS WAY:
_________________________
IF shouldBeRemoved(object)
   object.finalize();
   remove(object);
```

After `finalize` executes, GC will check once more if the object should still be removed. To qualify for removal, an object shouldn't be referenced from any object that is reachable from the root objects.

```
IT WORKS THIS WAY
_________________
LABEL
IF shouldBeRemoved(object)
    object.finalize();
    IF shouldBeRemoved(object)
        remove(object);
    ELSE
        GOTO LABEL
```

Let's imagine the following case:

```
class Foo {
    Application a;

    Foo(){};

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        this.a = Application.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Where `Application` is a class which represents the root object of the `Application`. In this case, as `a` is still reachable, the object of class `Foo` that qualified for removal right before, has just resurrected.

**IMPORTANT REMARK**

You are not guaranteed, that the `finalize` will be called, as it requires another object to take care of `finalize` method being called, so in case there is no enough free space on the heap, object might be destroyed without calling `finalize`.

Comment: How does assigning the `Application` instance to an instance variable keep that same instance reachable? It isn't assigning a reference to `this` to some other location, so I don't see how the instance is reachable via its own instance variable.

Comment: Regarding "object might be destroyed without calling `finalize`", that is false. Also, I do not understand "it requires another object to take care of `finalize` method being called". What other object? That doesn't ring true either.